# Copy image from url results in corrupt image

Tags: php, image, copy, file-get-contents, file-put-contents

I have a problem trying to copy the image from [this](http://awards.createdirect.ro/thumb/900/900/image/award/v1/Despre%20Spa%20100.jpg) link into my local directory.

You can find 2 other images with the same problem:

[First http://awards.createdirect.ro/thumb/900/900/image/award/v1/Despre%20Spa%20200.jpg](http://awards.createdirect.ro/thumb/900/900/image/award/v1/Despre%20Spa%20200.jpg)

[Second http://awards.createdirect.ro/thumb/900/900/image/award/v1/Despre%20Spa%20300.jpg](http://awards.createdirect.ro/thumb/900/900/image/award/v1/Despre%20Spa%20300.jpg)

With any other image works ok but when I'm trying to copy this one the image is corrupt.

Right now I'm using the `copy()` function from php.

I've also tried with `file_get_contents / file_put_contents` but it's the same thing.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
test@test:/tmp$ wget  http://awards.createdirect.ro/thumb/900/900/image/award/v1/Despre%20Spa%20300.jpg
--2016-09-23 16:37:01--  http://awards.createdirect.ro/thumb/900/900/image/award/v1/Despre%20Spa%20300.jpg
Resolving awards.createdirect.ro (awards.createdirect.ro)... 193.189.99.27
Connecting to awards.createdirect.ro (awards.createdirect.ro)|193.189.99.27|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 500 Internal Server Error
2016-09-23 16:37:03 ERROR 500: Internal Server Error.
```

It seems something wrong with the server.